# How can I view actually stored transformed Solr text field values?

Tags: solr

When Solr returns a document, the field values match those that where passed to the Solr indexer.

However especially for `TextField`s Solr typically uses a modified value where (depending on the definition in the `schema.xml`) various filters are applied, typicall:

- conversion to lower case
- replacing of synonyms
- removal of stopwords
- application of stemming

One can see the result of the conversion for specific texts by using Solr Admin > Some core > Analysis. There is a tool called [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) and the [LukeRequestHandler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/LukeRequestHandler.html) but it seems I can only view the values passed to Solr but not the tranformed variant. One can also take a look at the index data on the disk but they seem to be stored in a binary format.

However, non of these seem to enable me to see the actual value as stored.

The reason for asking is that I've created a text field based on a certain filter chain which according to Solr Admin > Analysis transforms the text correctly. However when searching for a specific word in the transformed text it won't find it.

Comment: Since you've already found the analysis page - you can enter both the text you've stored and the text you're querying with - include the output from that page, and show that the tokens from your query also are present on the indexed side. Also remember that any change to the `index` part of an analysis chain require you to reindex your collection by submitting the documents again, since tokenization and filtering is a lossy process.